# How to solve system.invalidcastexception in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Well, i have this piece of code. I want to store the contents of a textbox into an array of strings (i prefered to do it with a list of strings) and then to print each element of the array into another textbox. However when i try to compile this code i get this error message:
System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "" to int is not valid'
FormatException: input string is not in the correct format

Any suggestions?

```
Public Class NewUser

Dim textUser As String
Dim strUserName As New List(Of String)
Private Sub btnCreateUser_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCreateUser.Click
    textUser = txtNewUser.Text
    If textUser <> "" Then
        strUserName.Add(textUser)
        txtNewUser.Clear()
    Else
        MsgBox("Username or Password is missing. Try again!")
    End If
    For Each i As String In strUserName
        TextBox1.Text = String.Join(",", strUserName(i))
    Next i
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: @David    TextBox1.Text = String.Join(",", strUserName(i))

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear to me at all what you're trying to do here:

```
For Each i As String In strUserName
    TextBox1.Text = String.Join(",", strUserName(i))
Next i
```

For starters, `i` is a string and you're trying to use it like an integer as an index of an array.  But even if you were to correct it to this:

```
String.Join(",", i)
```

That's still trying to join *one string*.  That probably won't compile either, but even if it does it won't logically do anything.  Aside from that, you're overwriting `TextBox1.Text` every time the loop iterates, so *at best* it's only ever going to equal the last value in the array.

If you're just trying to join the array into that text box, that's one line:

```
TextBox1.Text = String.Join(",", strUserName)
```

No loop required.

Comment: Well i am new to vb.net and i thought that i had to use a loop in order to get all the elements in the list. Thank you very much it worked!

Comment: @ierostsant: You *could*, but the body of the loop would look more like: `TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + i + ","`  But then you'd also need to account for the extra comma at the end, either by removing it afterward or by adding a conditional inside the loop based on the length of the array or something.  It's easier to just use `String.Join()` for this exact reason.  But since `String.Join()` expects an array, no loop is needed.  You just give it the whole array and it internally loops over that array.